# how to open url webview in xamarin.form

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to open this url(http://localhost:8080/) when application is launched. Can any one please help i'm new in xamarin And my MainPage.xaml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App3"
             x:Class="App3.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <WebView Source="http://localhost:8080/" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

What URL are you trying to open? Note that `localhost` on your device means that you want to show a webpage that is hosted on your device. If you are trying to show a webpage hosted on your development machine, please figure out the network address that is reachable from your device. It will probably start with `192.168.x.x` or `10.x.x.x`.

Comment: i also mentioned <WebView Source="http://192.168.x.x:8080/" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/> but nothing happen it is still showing label message"Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"

Comment: Does it work with google.com? Also are you trying this on Android or iOS? iOS 9+ does not allow unsecure connections anymore

Comment: i want that when application is launched it should open url act as webview

Comment: I understand, but I think you need to figure out it the WebView is shown at all. So try loading google.com and see if that shows up. If not, you might want to try a `Grid` instead of a `StackLayout`. A `StackLayout` will only take up as much space as needed. And since the `WebView` doesn't know how big a page will be it might not show. You could also try to give the `WebView` a `WidthRequest` and a `HeightRequest`